# webpack 2 multiple entries yet use react hot loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I used this and it work in webpack 1

```
entry: {
    vendor  : ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'classnames', 'lodash', 'alt'],
    app     : ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
                'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
                path.resolve(__dirname, PATHS.app, 'entries', 'app.js')],
         otherFile : ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
                'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
                path.resolve(__dirname, PATHS.app, 'entries', 'otherFile.js')]
}
```

But this won't work in webpack 2, it worked when I removed the landing property. How do I use HMR and multiple entires? in this guide https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/ it used array but in my case I'm also using multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the complete config?

I was having an issue, but it turned out that the culprit was a misconfigured proxy.

I had it set to something like for webpack 1:

```
   proxy: {
        '/api*': {
            target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000',
            secure: false
        },
        '/admin': {
            bypass: () => 'admin.html'
        }
    },
```

But in webpack 2 I had to change it to:

```
     proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000',
            secure: false,
            bypass: (req, res, opts) => {
                if (req.originalUrl === '/admin') {
                    return 'admin.html';
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

In your files, where are you trying to point path.resolve to? I have the webpack config on the root directory, and it lets me just do:

```
entry: {
    main: [
         'babel-polyfill',
         'whatwg-fetch',
         'react-hot-loader/patch',
         'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8000',
         'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
         './app/components/main.jsx'
    ]
}
```

Comment: your above entry will work because it's just single entry point.

Comment: @Mellisa, no it isn't, it is just a single snippet of a multiple entry points configuration.

[Here's the full thing](https://hastebin.com/olepezadac.js)